# VISX avoid floats on Y axis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visx

How to avoid floats on Y axis?

**Note**: I dont want to use `Math.round` since it breaks the axis. Is there anything in VISX similar to CHART.js `precision`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can format axis ticks without modifying the underlying data and breaking the axis, using **tickFormat**. tickFormat can consume any function that controls how ticks are labeled.

VisX is built on d3.js, you can read about its tickFormat function here: https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/main/README.md#continuous_tickFormat

Here is an example axis:

```js
// function, that controls tick format

const formatValue = (value) => Math.round(value)

// Axis code in you component <SVG /> container

<AxisLeft
    tickTextFill={'#EDF2F7'}
    stroke={'#EDF2F7'}
    tickStroke={'#EDF2F7'}
    scale={yourScale}
    tickFormat={formatValue}
/>
```